# Azure App service -Deployment Center-Bit bucket account change not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have existing bit bucket account authorize and added into 
"Azure App service" --> "Deployment Center"

Now i want to replace different bit bucket account in same app service.
Azure give option  "change account" not working.

[image]

When i am clicking account change image is moving and giving same account again
[image]

Comment: Could you try to change the account in `Deployment options (Classic)`?

Comment: Hi, I took a look and it appears the call is returning a 401 for you which should show unauthorized and let you change it. I'm looking now into why this isn't behaving correctly. In the meantime, try what Joy said above with using Classic to change account.

Comment: I tried to change in classic option also but no luck,even deleted app and tried to configure but seems like bug in azure

Comment: My old account repo is building properly and fetching all changes so not agreed that return 401

Comment: Almost 3 years later, and still not a correctly working solution???   A window pops up, then goes away far to fast to see what happens..... 

NOTE: I am 99% certain this is NOT going to allow me to change to a Managed Identity that has been created....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to change my account too, and it had same problem just like yours.

And i think i have solved the problem. You need go to [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview) and log out your account like this.[image]

Then sign in the account you want azure deployment center replaced, and go back to azure deployment center, now try to change the account. This works for mine.

Hope this could help you, if you still have questions, please let me know.